# Insert into existing PDF document a title or an image using iTextSharp ? NOT STAMP

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, pdf, itext

I have a PDF document and I need to add a text to the top of first page. This is not a watermark or stamp. It's an ordinary text.
How can I do this?

Maybe I need to parse my PDF document and create a new one adding text? But how to do this? how to parse existing pdf document into new one? without copying pages, because in this case the text will be in the first page and other content in the new one.

I have found this method. But it won't help, because it only copies pages to the new ones. And I'll get "textTextText" in the first page and other content in the new ones.

```
public void ExtractPage(string sourcePdfPath, string outputPdfPath, 
int pageNumber, string password = "<span style="color: rgb(139, 0, 0);">")
{
PdfReader reader = null;
Document document = null;
PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;

try
{
    // Intialize a new PdfReader instance with the contents of the source Pdf file:
    reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath);

    // Capture the correct size and orientation for the page:
    document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber));

    // Initialize an instance of the PdfCopyClass with the source 
    // document and an output file stream:
    pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(document, 
        new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

    document.Open();

    // Extract the desired page number:
    importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber);
    pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
    document.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
}
```

Comment: I have a PDF document with text. I need to change it by adding a piece of text at the beginning. Thus, the entire text should be drifted down

Comment: This is an impossible-to-fulfill requirement, because of the nature of the PDF format. It's a format designed for **publication**, not **edition**.

Comment: As others have said, PDFs cannot "reflow". This is actually something that's built into the spec itself. Each element, be it text, a shape or an image, is drawn at specific x,y locations. Any "flow" is handled by the authoring applications. The "line breaks" in "paragraphs" are actually unrelated text drawing commands pre-calculated by the  _authoring application_ that just happen to visually be near each other. A "line" itself could actually be one or dozens of individual commands. Since everything is absolute there is no "flow" and there can not be "reflow".

Comment: However, if you are okay with just "moving everything down", you could  just use a stamper on a new document, import your old pages offset vertically by however many pixels you need and then write your text on the top. As long as you know how far "down" you need to move things this would actually be rather easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisHaas . Actually I haven't succeeded with "moving everything down". But I'm very grateful to you for your informative reply.